# How can I display WordPress posts on a sub domain not running wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have recently taken over a site which has a wordpress blog on a subdomain. I need to list all the posts on a 'news' page.

The page I need to display it on is a HTML page. I have looked into doing an RSS feed but had no luck. I've also looked into pulling the data from the database but I lack the skills!

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

> I have looked into doing an RSS feed but had no luck.

That's the best way to do it. What doesn't work?

See [Developer's Guide - Google AJAX Feed API - Google Code](https://developers.google.com/feed/) and [Magpie RSS - PHP RSS Parser](http://magpierss.sourceforge.net/)

Or see http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website for code examples and list the posts.